# Concat undetermined api call using rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I would like query an Api that returns dada and `next` item that contains the next url to call.

When `next` is null it means that all data is sent.

```
  getData(url?: any) {
    if (!url) {
      url = `https....../geojson/geo/?srid=xxx&code=xx&jsonb_as_text=false&page_size=10`;
    }
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { headers }).pipe(
      flatMap((res: any) => {
        if (res.next) {
          this.getData(res.next);
        }
        return res;
      })
    );
  }
```

Actually the component only gets the first call but not the second.

How can I chain well api calls and concat the results then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `expand` operator. It is recursive - each response calls the operator callback. You can use `toArray` to collect all responses as an array. You could use `scan` or no operator to process immediate results while the others are loading.

```
getData(url) {
   return this.httpClient.get(url, { headers })
}

getAllData() {
  
    const url = `https....../geojson/geo/?srid=xxx&code=xx&jsonb_as_text=false&page_size=10`;
    
    return this.getData(url).pipe(
      expand((res: any) => {
        if (res.next) {
          return this.getData(res.next);
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
      toArray(),
      map(responses => responses.flatMap(response => response.items))
    );
  }
```